# How to play this in internet explorer?

Tags: html, flash

this is my code for player its not working in internet explorer.
can anyone help me.
how to make it work in all browsers?

```
<object 
  data="http://bitcast-b.bitgravity.com/player/6/bitgravity_player_v6_1_4.swf"
  id="bitgravity_player_6" 
  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
  height="350" width="500">
      <param value="true" name="allowFullScreen">
      <param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
      <param value="File=http://bglive-a.bitgravity.com/maa/live/newstream&amp;Mode=live&amp;AutoPlay=true&amp;BufferTime=1.5&amp;VideoFit=automatic&amp;DefaultRatio=1.777778&amp;LogoImage=http://musicking.in/images/playerlogo.png&amp;LogoPosition=bottomright&amp;LogoLink=http://musicking.in&amp;ColorBase=#000000&amp;ColorControl=#666666&amp;ColorHighlight=#99FF00&amp;ColorFeature=#99FF00" name="flashvars">
</object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the object tag:

```
<param name="movie" 
 value="http://bitcast-b.bitgravity.com/player/6/bitgravity_player_v6_1_4.swf"/>
```

To make it work in all browsers you need to use both [object and embed](http://www.w3schools.com/flash/flash_inhtml.asp) tags.

You might also wanna check out [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) which is a javascript flash detection and embedding script and does all the dirty work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://bitcast-b.bitgravity.com/player/6/bitgravity_player_v6_1_4.swf" width="500" height="350">
<!-- <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="500" height="350">
    <param name="movie" value="http://bitcast-b.bitgravity.com/player/6/bitgravity_player_v6_1_4.swf" />
<!--><!-- http://Validifier.com -->
  </object>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried configuring the player using the online setup wizard on BitGravity's site?

http://player.bitgravity.com/6/simple/source.php